# Terraform vsphere multiple disk - Identify on linux

Tags: linux, terraform, rhel, terraform-provider-vsphere

We currently deploy virtual machines (vesphere) with an variable amount of disks using dynamic disk block. In linux we have to format/mount etc. them manually later. Now I want to automate that too with a script executed from terraform on the operating system.

But how can I identify the disks? Lets assume I attach 3 additional disks to a VM. I could hope and assume that disk 1 is /dev/sdb, disk 2 is /dev/sdc and so on. But thats not really how I want to apply that. Is there a way to put a label on the disk that is actually seen in the operating system (rhel linux) so I can be 100% sure that I work with the disk I want to?

```
  dynamic "disk" {
for_each = var.data_disks
content {
  label             = "disk${disk.value["lun"]}"
  size              = disk.value["disk_size_gb"]
  filesystem        = disk.value["filesystem"]
  mountpoint        = disk.value["mountpoint"]
  mountopts         = disk.value["mountopts"]
  unit_number       = disk.value["lun"]
  storage_policy_id = var.vsphere_storage_policy_id
  eagerly_scrub     = var.eagerly_scrub
  thin_provisioned  = var.thin_provisioned
}
```

}

filesystem, mountpoint and mountopts are things I add over a json file and plan to use for the bash-script.
The "label" is not available in linux.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you already tried? Do you have Terraform code? Can you write Terraform code and then do some testing to see what gets created?

Comment: Added the code, the script will be bash. I can test the terraform code so far, I already have a VM with 10 disks (bash script is not operative yet).

Comment: This is really more a question about your software provisioning code than your infrastructure provisioning code. Your soft prov code should be able to automatically identify the devices to do this functionality. This would be separate from Terraform.